# Cumulative Product of Template Parameter Pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to initialise a static and constant array with the cumulative product of a template parameter pack:

```
template <int ...D>
class Foo
{
     static const std::array<const Size, sizeof...(D)> _array;
};
template <int...D> const std::array<const int, sizeof...(D)> Foo<D...>::_array = 
{ cumulative_product<D...>() };
```

How do I write the function cumulative_product<>(), such that it transforms D... into the cumulative product of D...? E.g.

```
Foo<1,2,3,4>::_array;// = {1,1*2,1*2*3,1*2*3*4} = {1,2,6,24}.
```

---

**Solution:** Massive thank you to @bogdan for your excellent C++14 solution, and improvements to my C++11 solution.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define CPP_VERSION 11

#if CPP_VERSION >= 14

// Credit: @bogdan at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37373602/6367128
template<int... Args> constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> cumulative_product(int seed = 1) { return{ { seed *= Args ... } }; }

#elif CPP_VERSION == 11

// Acknowledgement: Huge thank you to @bogdan for making the code more portable, concise and readable!
namespace details
{
   template<int N, int i, int j, int ...Args> struct c_product_gen               // N counts down to zero
   {
      static constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)+1> get() { return c_product_gen<N - 1, i*j, Args..., i*j>::get(); }
   };
   template<int i, int j, int ...Args> struct c_product_gen<0, i, j, Args...>    // The end point of the template recursion
   {
      static constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)+1> get() { return { { j, Args... } }; }
   };
}

template<int... Args> constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> cumulative_product() { return details::c_product_gen<sizeof...(Args), 1, Args...>::get(); }

#else // CPP_VERSION < 11

template<int... Args> constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> cumulative_product() 
{ 
    static_assert(false, "C++ version 11 or greater is required.");
    return std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)>();
}

#endif

int main()
{
   constexpr auto a = cumulative_product<1,2,3,4,5>();
   for(auto i : a) std::cout << i << ' ';    // Output: 1 2 6 24 120 
   std::cout << '\n';  
}
```

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I like the rotation of the arguments, nice one! Note that Clang and GCC in pedantic mode will complain about a few template technicalities that are worth fixing for maximum portability and Standard conformance. In particular, GCC and EDG correctly catch an important one that Clang and MSVC ignore - the partial specialization of `c_product_gen` needs to be more specialized than the primary template. Incidentally, fixing that makes `remove_first` unnecessary. [Here's a version](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hHfoKAlqwayCWmSt) with all the adjustments.

Comment: @bogdan Your improvements are awesome :) thank you so much! I've updated my answer with your improvements and tried to credit you appropriately (please do let me know if I've done this incorrectly). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <int... D, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(D)> cumulative_product(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(D), "Missing initializers");
    int a[]{ D... };
    for (int i = 1; i < int(sizeof...(D)); ++i)
    {
        a[i] *= a[i-1];
    }
    return {{ a[Is]... }};
}

template <int... D>
constexpr auto cumulative_product()
{
    return cumulative_product<D...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(D)>{});
}

template <int... D>
struct Foo
{
     static constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(D)> _array  = cumulative_product<D...>();
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/383705b56ae856a6)

Comment: Thank you very much for an excellent answer! Just out of curiosity, how could you do it with just C++11? Or is it impossible?

Comment: For C++14, even something as simple as `template<int... Ds> constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Ds)> cumulative_product(int seed = 1) { return {{seed *= Ds ...}}; }` is enough. @Judge: a C++11 solution is definitely possible, but I don't think you can avoid using recursion to fake iteration, and it's really not worth the trouble.

Comment: @bogdan I have to say that your solution is just plain awesome.